# Is it possible to invoke a component on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

Previously there was a `<div>`, the contents of which i was toggling on `ng-click`. With components in Angular 1.5, i moved the contents of the `<div>`and created a `component`. I want to load this `component` on `ng-click` now.

Is this possible ?

I did not find any help yet. If possible, a help would be great.

Comment: Could you please, extend a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to show/hide the component (having your div content). I have created a plnkr, refer the below code and plnkr link

https://plnkr.co/edit/sZSfslXTDGfvGwiDdBSZ?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="componentApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="componentController">
    <button ng-click="showComponent()" id="changeText">Show Component</button>
    <div-content ng-if="isShowContent"></div-content>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("componentApp", [])
       .controller("componentController", function($scope) {
         $scope.isShowContent = false;
         $scope.showComponent = function() {
           $scope.isShowContent = !$scope.isShowContent;
           document.getElementById("changeText").innerHTML = $scope.isShowContent ? "Hide Component" : "Show Component";
         };
       })
       .component("divContent", {
         template: "This is the content of my div"
       });
```